# How to scp and compress simultaneously without decompressing on the destination machine

Tags: linux, bash

I would like a efficient method to scp a huge directory to a machine, while simultaneously compressing the directory. I need only the compressed directory in the destination machine.

Is it possible without having to do this in  2 steps manually?

Comment: Take a look at the `rsync` utility instead. Much more flexible and mighty and it can also connect via `ssh`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use tar:

```
tar cfz - /path/to/local|ssh user@remotehost 'cd /desired/location; tar xfz -'
```

the local tar will create/compress your file structure, and output it to `stdout` (`-` for the filename), which gets piped through ssh to a tar on the remote host, which reads the compressed stream from stdin (`-` filename, again) and extracts the contents

If you only want the compressed file written out, then

```
 tar ... | ssh user@remotehoust 'cat - > file.tar.gz'
```

Comment: Hi, another question, how can I modify this command to have a more visual sense of what is going on . Waiting for command line to return is confusing at times

Comment: with the parameter `-v` like `tar cfvz` or `tar xfvz`